# Get secret value from azure key vault in variable in powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

I need to set secret value from azure key vault into a variable to be used in further task. I tried below script but it gives error: Could not find the modules: 'Az.Accounts' with Version: ''.
I understand that I can use variable directly but it needs to be set to a common variable since I am building generic pipeline

Script I tried:

```
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'SUB1'
              ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
              Inline: |
                $secret = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName '$(KeyVaultName)' -Name $(sqlServerAdminUsername)
                                $ssPtr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($secret.SecretValue)
                                try {
                                   $SqlServerUsername = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($ssPtr)
                                } finally {
                                   [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeBSTR($ssPtr)
                                }
              azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
              pwsh: true
            condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['EnvironmentType'], 'Dev'))
```

Comment: Unsure about the error but `'$(KeyVaultName)'` should be between double quotes if you want the variable to expand. Also, just as a FYI, you can reduce the complexity of getting the Secure string to text by using `([pscredential]::new('U', $secret.SecretValue)).GetNetworkCredential().Password`.

Comment: It might be a casing issue. Try `scriptType: inlineScript` and `inline` instead of the current title case.

Comment: I tried to use the variable directly which was downloaded through AzureKeyVault task. But while trying to fetch it, I am using an intermediary common variable which points to variable in keyvalult like this - $($(DBUserName)). Here $(DBUSerName) has the value to key name. But, it does not return actual result

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Comment: @singhh-msft No. it does not work

Comment: Which build agent are you using?

Comment: If it is Windows, can you try running this task in Linux? And, also try running same task in 5.*

Comment: Check my updated response.

Comment: Does it help you?

Comment: No. I tried, doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [similar issue.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/3869)

*Fixes can be:*

- Try switching to version 3 and 5 of Powershell task and run.
- Run the Powershell V4 task in Linux hosted Agents instead of Windows.
- Run this powershell screipt from [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops).